# Creating Test in Jira using Rest Assured

Tags: gson, jira, rest-assured, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am new to Rest Assured and currently trying to create a JSON message for posting an issue of type TEST in Jira using Rest Assured. However, I am not able to properly create the test steps in the message. Below are the code and the message structure that I am getting.

```
TestStepMap teststep = new TestStepMap();
List<TestStepMap> s = new ArrayList<TestStepMap>();

for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    String step = "Step " + (i+1);
    String data = "Data " + (i+1);
    String result = "Result " + (i+1);

    teststep.setIndex(index);
    teststep.setStep(step);
    teststep.setData(data);
    teststep.setResult(result);

    s.add(i, teststep);
}

CustomField10011Map customfield_10011 = new CustomField10011Map();
customfield_10011.setSteps(s);
```

This is the output that I am getting.

```
{
    "fields": {
        "project": {
            "key": "RT"
        },
        "summary": "Sum of two numbers",
        "description": "example of manual test",
        "issuetype": {
            "name": "Test"
        },
        "customfield_10007": {
            "value": "Manual"
        },
        "customfield_10011": {
            "steps": [
                {
                    "index": 3,
                    "step": "Step 4",
                    "data": "Data 4",
                    "result": "Result 4"
                },
                {
                    "index": 3,
                    "step": "Step 4",
                    "data": "Data 4",
                    "result": "Result 4"
                },
                {
                    "index": 3,
                    "step": "Step 4",
                    "data": "Data 4",
                    "result": "Result 4"
                },
                {
                    "index": 3,
                    "step": "Step 4",
                    "data": "Data 4",
                    "result": "Result 4"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The test steps 1, 2 and 3 are being overwritten by the last step. How can I solve the issue? Any suggestions are highly welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the **same** `teststep` instance to list `s` every time.

What you want is to create and add a new TestStepMap object per iteration, otherwise you'll always be overwriting updates on that object from an earlier iteration of the loop.

```
List<TestStepMap> s = new ArrayList<TestStepMap>();

for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    String step = "Step " + (i+1);
    String data = "Data " + (i+1);
    String result = "Result " + (i+1);

    TestStepMap teststep = new TestStepMap();
    teststep.setIndex(index);
    teststep.setStep(step);
    teststep.setData(data);
    teststep.setResult(result);

    s.add(i, teststep);
}
```